# How to manipulate a CSV file with sed or awk?

Tags: sed, awk, csv

How can I do the following to a CSV file using `sed` or `awk`?

- Delete a column
- Duplicate a column
- Move a column

I have a big table with over 200 rows, and I'm not that familiar with `sed`.

Comment: Unless you need to run on a system that only has basic tools available, see [Is there a robust command line tool for processing csv files?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7425)

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for the edit, the link was helpful too.

Comment: @OP complex CSV manipulation is much more reliably solved in a scripting language like Perl or Ruby.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aside from how to cut and re-arrange the fields (covered in the other answers), there is the issue of quirky CSV fields.

If your data falls into this "quirky" category, a bit of *pre* and *post* filtering can take care of it. The filters shown below require the characters `\x01`,`\x02`,`\x03`,`\x04` to not appear anywhere in your data.

Here are the filters wrapped around a simple `awk` field dump.

*Note:* **field-five** has an invalid/incomplete "quoted field" layout, but it is benign at the end of a row (depending on the CSV parser). But, of course, it would cause *problematic unexpedted results* if it were to be swapped away from its current *end-of-row* position.

Update; *user121196* has pointed out a bug when a comma precedes a trailing quote. Here is the fix.

The data

```
cat <<'EOF' >file
field one,"fie,ld,two",field"three","field,\",four","field,five
"15111 N. Hayden Rd., Ste 160,",""
EOF
```

The code

```
sed -r 's/^/,/; s/\\"/\x01/g; s/,"([^"]*)"/,\x02\1\x03/g; s/,"/,\x02/; :MC; s/\x02([^\x03]*),([^\x03]*)/\x02\1\x04\2/g; tMC; s/^,// ' file |
  awk -F, '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s\n", $i; print NL}' |
    sed -r 's/\x01/\\"/g; s/(\x02|\x03)/"/g; s/\x04/,/g'
```

The output:

```
field one
"fie,ld,two"
field"three"
"field,\",four"
"field,five

"15111 N. Hayden Rd., Ste 160,"
""
```

---

Here is the *pre filter*, expanded with comments.
The *post filter* is just a reversal of `\x01`.`\x02`,`\x03`,`\x04`

```
sed -r '
    s/^/,/                # add a leading comma delimiter
    s/\\"/\x01/g          # obfuscate escaped quotation-mark (\")
    s/,"([^"]*)"/,\x02\1\x03/g    # obfuscate quotation-marks
    s/,"/,\x02/           # when no trailing quote on last field  
    :MC                   # obfuscate commas embedded in quotes
    s/\x02([^\x03]*),([^\x03]*)/\x02\1\x04\2/g
    tMC
    s/^,//                # remove spurious leading delimiter
'
```

Comment: how would you delete the nth column based on this filter?

Comment: @user121196 - As mentioned in its opening sentence, this answer shows a way to make the CSV data more consistent.. eg. by termporarily replacing a quote-embedded comma with a neutral token character... and then reverting it back into a comma *after* the move/cut/delete.  Again, as mentioned, the move/cut/delete step is replaced by *a simple awk field-dump*.

Answer (score 19):

This depends on whether your CSV file uses commas only for delimiters, or if you have madness like:

> field one,"field,two",field three

This assumes you're using a simple CSV file:

#### Removing a column

You can get rid of a single column many ways; I used column 2 as an example. The easiest way is probably to use `cut`, which lets you specify a delimiter `-d` and which fields you want to print `-f`; this tells it to split on commas and output field 1, and fields 3 through the end:

```
$ cut -d, -f1,3- /path/to/your/file
```

If you actually need to use `sed`, you can write a regular expression that matches the first `n-1` fields, the `n`th field, and the rest, and skip outputting the `n`th (here `n` is 2, so the first group is matched `1` time: `\{1\}`):

```
$ sed 's/\(\([^,]\+,\)\{1\}\)[^,]\+,\(.*\)/\1\3/' /path/to/your/file
```

There are a number of ways to do this in `awk`, none of them particularly elegant. You can use a `for` loop, but dealing with the trailing comma is a pain; ignoring that it'd be something like:

```
$ awk -F, '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if(i != 2) printf "%s,", $i; print NL}' /path/to/your/file
```

I find it easier to output field 1 and then use `substr` to pull off everything after field 2:

```
$ awk -F, '{print $1 "," substr($0, length($1)+length($2)+3)}' /path/to/your/file
```

This is annoying for columns further along though

#### Duplicating a column

In `sed` this is essentially the same expression as before, but you also capture the target column and include that group multiple times in the replacement:

```
$ sed 's/\(\([^,]\+,\)\{1\}\)\([^,]\+,\)\(.*\)/\1\3\3\4/' /path/to/your/file
```

In `awk` the for loop way it'd be something like (again ignoring the trailing comma):

```
$ awk -F, '{
for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
    if(i == 2) printf "%s,", $i;
    printf "%s,", $i
}
print NL
}' /path/to/your/file
```

The `substr` way:

```
$ awk -F, '{print $1 "," $2 "," substr($0, length($1)+2)}' /path/to/your/file
```

(tcdyl came up with a better method in [his answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26942/73))

#### Moving a column

I think the `sed` solution follows naturally from the others, but it starts to get ridiculously long

Answer (score 15):

`awk` is your best bet. `awk` prints fields by number, so...

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=","; OFS=","; } {print $1,$2,$3}' file
```

To remove a column, not print it:

```
 awk 'BEGIN { FS=","; OFS=","; } {print $1,$3}' file
```

To change the order:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=","; OFS=","; } {print $3,$1,$2}' file
```

Re-direct to an output file.

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=","; OFS=","; } {print $3,$1,$2}' file > output.file
```

`awk` can format the output as well.

[Awk format output](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_7.html)

Answer (score 5):

Given a space-delimited file in the following format:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

You can remove field 2 with awk like so:

```
awk '{ sub($2,""); print}' file
```

which returns

```
1  3 4 5
```

Replace column 2 with column n where appropriate.

To duplicate column 2,

```
awk '{ col = $2 " " $2; $2 = col; print }' file
```

which returns

```
1 2 2 3 4 5
```

To switch column 2 and 3,

```
awk '{temp = $2; $2 = $3; $3 = temp; print}'
```

which returns

```
1 3 2 4 5
```

awk is generally very good at dealing with the concept of *fields*. If you're dealing with a CSV, and not a space-delimited file, you can simply use

```
awk -F,
```

to define your field as a comma, instead of a space (which is the default). There are a number of good awk resources online, one of which I list as a source below.

[Source](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/awk1line.txt) for #3

Comment: I don't know much about `awk`, but it seems to output space-separated even if the field separator is `,` (the field-separator just controls how it handles input)

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: yes, it is OFS awk variable that controls output field separator.

Comment: Yes, and as I mention in my answer, you can pass the -F option to awk to change the delimiter (e.g. -F,)

Answer (score 0):

To work with CSV data, it is usually better to use a CSV-aware tool such as [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or the ones provided by [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Both `sed` and `awk` are generic text-processing utilities that do not know anything about CSV and its quoting rules etc.

Test data:

```
id,name,date of birth
1,"Alfonso, the first",1980-01-01
2,"Betty, the second",1980-01-02
3,"Conny, the third",1982-02-21
```

---

To delete the `name` field using the csvkit tools:

```bash
$ csvcut -C name file
id,date of birth
1,1980-01-01
2,1980-01-02
3,1982-02-21
```

To duplicate the `name` field using csvkit:

```bash
$ csvcut -c id,name,name,"date of birth" file
id,name,name,date of birth
1,"Alfonso, the first","Alfonso, the first",1980-01-01
2,"Betty, the second","Betty, the second",1980-01-02
3,"Conny, the third","Conny, the third",1982-02-21
```

To move the `date of birth` field first using csvkit:

```bash
$ csvcut -c "date of birth",id,name file
date of birth,id,name
1980-01-01,1,"Alfonso, the first"
1980-01-02,2,"Betty, the second"
1982-02-21,3,"Conny, the third"
```

---

To delete the `name` field using Miller:

```bash
$ mlr --csv cut -x -f name file
id,date of birth
1,1980-01-01
2,1980-01-02
3,1982-02-21
```

To duplicate the `name` field using Miller (creates `name2` as a new field at the end):

```bash
$ mlr --csv put '$name2 = $name' file
id,name,date of birth,name2
1,"Alfonso, the first",1980-01-01,"Alfonso, the first"
2,"Betty, the second",1980-01-02,"Betty, the second"
3,"Conny, the third",1982-02-21,"Conny, the third"
```

To move the `date of birth` to the start of the record using Miller:

```bash
$ mlr --csv reorder -f "date of birth" file
date of birth,id,name
1980-01-01,1,"Alfonso, the first"
1980-01-02,2,"Betty, the second"
1982-02-21,3,"Conny, the third"
```