# Reindexing a large CSV file

Tags: files, sed, awk, csv

I went through the answers in [this helpful thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26941/how-to-manipulate-a-csv-file-with-sed-or-awk?lq=1), but my problem seems to be different enough that I can't think of good answer (at least with `sed`).

I have a large CSV file (200+ GB) with rows that look like the following:

```
<alphanumerical_identifier>,<number>
```

where `<alphanumerical_identifier>` is unique across the entire file. I would like to create a separate file that **replaces the first column by an index**, i.e.

```
<index>,<number>
```

so that we get:

```
1, <number>
2, <number>
3, <number>
```

Can `awk` generate an increasing index without loading the full file in memory?

Since the index increases monotonically, it may be even better to just drop the index. Would the solution for that be that different?, i.e.:

```
<number>
<number>
<number>
```

Comment: I am not sure about this solution's feasibility. But how about just generating as many numbers as in the CSV file in a separate file and then just appending the second column of the CSV file to that file?

Comment: @Ramesh That is perfectly fine as long as the output is correct.

Comment: try : `perl -pe '$_ = "$.,$_"' bigfile.csv > newfile.csv` but it would load full file in the memory, not sure

Comment: I suspect I'm misunderstanding something; otherwise, `awk -F, '{print ++n, $2}'` would work. Or `awk -F, '{print $2}'` for the second variation.

Comment: @G-Man, that's probably it although `FNR` would serve just as well as `++n`

Comment: I'd triple-check that you really can get rid of that Uniq Identifier... why not add a first (3rd) column with the index, but still keep the identifier? isn't that identifier used **anywhere** else?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not near a terminal to test, but how about the oft-overlooked `nl` command?  Something like:

`cut -f 2 -d , original.csv | nl -w 1 -p -s , > numbered.csv`

Comment: P.S.: A *200GB* CSV file?  Wow, and I thought working with the North American Ported Number Database as a CSV (a couple of DVD) was huge!

Comment: It works, although there is a big blank after the number. I would replace it with: `cut -d, -f 2- /tmp/aa | nl -w 1 -p -s ,`

Comment: @Angel: Thanks, updated my answer to use the width option `-w 1` instead of left-numbering.

Comment: Thanks @bishop - Where do the input and output filenames go?

Comment: @user815423426 Haha, yeah, whoops... the file names.  Added them.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I know the answer, but if I just want to preserve the second column? (as per my OP update): First part of the command is enough?)

Comment: @user815423426 Yes, the `cut` command before the pipe symbol (`|`) will give you just the second column, effectively having implicit line numbers.

Answer (score 7):

Here are a few approaches, but none will approach the speed of the `cut` and `nl` solution above:

1. awk

   ```
   awk -F, '{$1=NR;print $1","$2;}' file.csv > newfile.csv
   ```
2. Perl

   ```
   perl -pe 's/[^,]+/$./' file.csv > newfile.csv
   ```

   or

   ```
   perl -F, -ane '$F[0]=$.; print join ",", @F' file.csv
   ```
3. Shell (but I don't recommend it for a 200G file, it will take ages)

   ```
   i=1; while IFS=, read foo num; do 
           printf "%d,%s\n" $((i++)) $num; 
   done < file.csv > newfile.csv
   ```

The above solutions are sorted in order of speed. I tested on my laptop and a 40M file and they took (average of 10 runs) 2.2282 (awk), 2.4555 (1st perl), 3.1825s (2nd perl) and a whopping 48.6035s for the shell. The very clever `cut` and `nl` solution you already have was about 4 times faster at 0.6078s.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the stats!  The shell result surprises me, somewhat. If you replace `printf` with `echo`, does the timing significantly improve?

Comment: 40G file processed in 2.2282 seconds?  Where can I get me that laptop?

Comment: @JohnB umm, yes, sorry, that was 40M, not G :)

Comment: I like the resetting of `$1` approach with `awk`.  The `cut` solution is definitely much faster, but that's to be expected as it doesn't replace `<alphanumerical_identifier>` with anything.  I think the fastest `awk` variant might be something like: `mawk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{$1=NR}1' file.csv > newfile.csv`.

Comment: @JohnB ah, yes, I would guess that using `OFS` instead of explicitly printing `,` would be slightly faster and that may well add up to a significant difference in  huge file.