# Remove Columns from a CSV File

Tags: text-processing, csv

I have a CSV file from which I need to remove one column from it.The problem is I have exported the CSV file without headers.So how can I remove the column from the CSV file.For example if I have the **example.csv** I want to remove the last column from it which is a boolean data and have the file as **input.csv**.

input.csv

```
1,"data",100.00,TRUE
2,"code",91.8,TRUE
3,"analytics",100.00,TRUE
```

output.csv

```
1,"data",100.00
2,"code",91.8
3,"analytics",100.00
```

Comment: What's wrong with having no headers?

Comment: You should clearly indicate that your complete CSV is this simplistic, i.e. no fields spanning multiple lines. Either give an example matching [tag:csv] or use [tag:csv-simple]. CSV is  much more complex format than most assume, and in only a extremely small subset of CSV files can be handled with "standard" text processing tools (sed, awk), the vast majority require parsing e.g. with Python/Perl/Ruby libraries.

Comment: Almost the same question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34646/is-there-a-command-line-spell-to-drop-a-column-in-a-csv-file

Answer (score 33):

To remove the fourth column,

```
$ cut -d, -f4 --complement example.csv > input.csv
```

Adjust the -f option to match the column number.

If the CSV file is more complicated, you could use some perl and the Text::CSV package,

```
$ perl -MText::CSV -E '$csv = Text::CSV->new({binary=>1}); 
  while ($row = $csv->getline(STDIN)) 
  {
    print "$row->[0],$row->[1],$row->[2]\n"
  }' < example.csv > input.csv
```

Comment: This is incorrect! CSV files may have multiline cells and those would be broken by this command.

Comment: @adius yes, the first command is pretty simple and can be broken by newlines, commas in quotes, etc.

The second command handles a much wider range of CSV quirks, including multi-line cells.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest using [miller](http://johnkerl.org/miller) (AKA `mlr`). Miller is a small (< 1 MB) program written in C (without dependencies) for processing tabular data in a variety of formats (e.g., TSV, CSV, tabular JSON, key-value pairs) in a streaming fashion. It is available from most Linux distros' repositories (usually under the name *miller*). Its CSV parser handles multi-line cells (i.e., cells with embedded newline characters). Although it assumes CSV files with headers, it has options (`--implicit-csv-header` and `--headerless-csv-output`) that handle header-less CSV files. For your use-case, assuming you want to remove the fourth column (column indexing begins with 1), you could do something like

```
mlr --csv --implicit-csv-header --headerless-csv-output cut -x -f 4 input.csv > output.csv
```

If you want to remove the last column without having to count them, you could reverse each CSV line prior to processing the data, and `rev`erse them again afterwards, like so:

```
< input.csv rev |
mlr --csv --implicit-csv-header --headerless-csv-output cut -x -f 1 |
rev > output.csv
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 7):

Use the csv module in Python:

```
python -c 'import sys,csv
w = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
for row in csv.reader(sys.stdin):
    w.writerow(row[0:-1])' < input.csv > output.csv
```

If you want the output to contain say columns 2, 3, and 1, in that order, use

```
python -c 'import sys,csv
w = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
for row in csv.reader(sys.stdin):
    w.writerow([row[1], row[2], row[0]])' < input.csv > output.csv
```

Python array indexes start at 0, so the column numbers are counted starting at zero too, above; that's why they are 1, 2, 0 for columns 2, 3, 1, respectively.

Comment: This answer is perfect and it helps that you've answered both the include and exclude variants of the module.

Answer (score 4):

`sed`:

```
sed 's/,[^,]\+$//' file.csv
```

- `,[^,]\+` matches `,` followed by any number of characters except `,`, and the match is replaced with empty string

`awk`:

```
awk -F, '{for(i=1; i<NF; i++) printf("%s%s", $i, FS); print ""}' file.csv
```

- `-F,` sets field delimiter as `,`
- `for(i=1; i<NF; i++) printf("%s", $i); print ""` iterates over the fields except the last one, and print the output in desired format

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt
1,"data",100.00,TRUE
2,"code",91.8,TRUE
3,"analytics",100.00,TRUE

% sed 's/,[^,]\+$//' file.txt                                     
1,"data",100.00
2,"code",91.8
3,"analytics",100.00

% awk -F, '{for(i=1; i<NF; i++) printf("%s%s", $i, FS); print ""}' file.txt
1,"data",100.00,
2,"code",91.8,
3,"analytics",100.00,
```

Answer (score 2):

CSV format is sometimes tricky: CSV-parsers is the way to go.

Taking the simplistic approach, removing last field:

1) remove last field with Awk

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{NF--;print}'
```

2) regex with perl

```
perl -pe 's/.*\K,.*//'
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to CSV-specific custom code in Python, Perl, or whatever else, there are projects, like **miller**, focused on processing CSV/TSV on the command line.

There's the Python project, [**csvkit**](https://github.com/wireservice/csvkit), which aims to offer some CSV-specific variants of common CL tools like **cut** and **grep**.  That project also inspired [**GoCSV**](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv) which aims to be faster and more memory efficient.

They both have **cut**-like syntax for specifying columns/fields with ranges, like:

```bsh
% csvcut -c 1-3 input.csv 
1,data,100.00
2,code,91.8
3,analytics,100.00
```

```bsh
% gocsv select -c 1-3 input.csv 
1,data,100.00
2,code,91.8
3,analytics,100.00
```

I'm not sure how these two compare to miller, but I like how the syntax looks shorter/clearer.

Answer (score 1):

just change the column number in this awk command. Below command removes the 3rd column. ( $3 )

```
awk -F, '{$3=""}1' OFS=, test.txt  | sed "s/^,//;s/,$//;s/,,/,/"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cut -d "," -f 4 --complement input.csv > output.csv
```

Here, `-d` is followed by the delimiter i.e. semi-colon(`;`) within double quotes, and `-f` is followed by the number of the column to be removed i.e. 4. The column numbers are starting from 1 and proceed in this context.

The `--complement` option indicates the complement of the selection. (This option enables the `cut` command to display all the bytes/characters or fields *except* the selected bytes)

In this scenario, the complement of the `cut` operation is all the columns delimited by `,` except the 4th column.

Comment: To make this answer more different from [the answer that gave the same solution 2 years earlier](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317366/remove-columns-from-a-csv-file/317367#317367), you can explain what `--complement` does.

Answer (score 0):

Very generic solution to remove number of last characters:

```
awk '{print substr($0, 1, length($0)-5)}' list1.txt
1,"data",100.00
2,"code",91.8
3,"analytics",100.00
```

`-5` is the number of character will be removed

Comment: this will break the csv if there's any `FALSE` values.