# Using CSV line as command parameters

Tags: shell, text-processing, pipe, csv

I have a CSV file like:

```
Name,Age,Address
Daniel Dvorkin,28,Some Address St. 1234
(... N ...)
Foo Bar,90,Other Address Av. 3210
```

And I have a command that take this parameters:

```
./mycommand --name="Daniel Dvorkin" --age=28 --address="Some Address St. 1234"
```

What is the easiest way to run *mycommand* for each line of the CSV?

Comment: Do you want name, age and address also from the CSV file?

Comment: nop. Just the data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's pretty easy:

```
sed '1d;s/\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\)/.\/mycommand --name="\1" --age="\2" --address="\3"/e' file.csv
```

`1d` will delete caption line.
`s` command will modify the string like in your example
`e` in the end of `s` command will execute the string. this is GNU extension, so if you don't have GNU sed, you can use `xargs` instead `e`:

```
sed '1d;s/\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\)/.\/mycommand --name="\1" --age="\2" --address="\3"/' file.csv | xargs
```

Comment: Is it possible that you're missing a close quote?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I did. But right now it is fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

If your CSV is simple CSV with no quoting mechanism (hence commas cannot appear in a field), you can do the parsing in the shell.

```
{
  read line  # ignore the header line
  IFS=,
  while read -r name age address; do
    ./mycommand --name="$name" --age="$age" --address="$address"
  done
} <input.csv
```

If fields can be quoted, you need a real CSV parser. Use [Perl, Python, R](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7425/is-there-a-robust-command-line-tool-for-processing-csv-files), Ruby or other languages.

Comment: How are you passing the file contents to this?

Comment: @MZAweb Oh, yeah. Redirect the input of that shell snippet from the file or pipe containing your data. See my edit.

Comment: +1 for the ‘simple CSV’ proviso. CSV is much harder to parse from the shell than its acronym would have you believe.

Comment: I like this one much more than the sed magic in accepted answer, as it is actually readable (i.e. usable).

Answer (score 2):

Besides sed, there is [awk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html)...

```
awk -F, 'NR > 1 { system("./mycommand --name=\\\"" $1 "\\\" --age=" $2 " --address=\\\"" $3 "\\\"") }' < file.csv
```

Comment: Love the simplicity of this one. Thanks!! Will test ASAP.

Comment: could you please explain what \\\ mean