# Can you specify an enclosure for cut?

Tags: cut

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a robust command line tool for processing csv files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7425/is-there-a-robust-command-line-tool-for-processing-csv-files)

I can use `cut` to extract columns from a file:

```
$ cat foo
foo,bar,hello
bash,baz,world

$ cut -d\, -f2 foo
bar
baz
```

But what if a column has a delimiter in it that is safe inside an enclosure like this?

```
$ cat foo
foo,"hello, world",bar
bash,goodbye,baz

$ cut -d\, -f2 temp12
"hello
goodbye
```

Is there some way to tell `cut` to respect the enclosure of quote `""` characters?

Comment: Strictly speaking, the answer is: no, you need a proper CSV parser.

Comment: You could quickly code up csv output script using some python or perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cut` could do it if you first preprocess its input to escape the characters inside the quotes (for instance, replace "_" with "_u" and "," with "_c" inside quotes, or replace every character with their 2-byte hex notation) and postprocess it to restore that escaping.

Something like:

```
perl -pe 's/"(.*?)"/"\"".unpack("H*", $1)."\""/ge' |
  cut -d, -f2 |
  perl -pe 's/"(.*?)"/"\"".pack("H*",$1)."\""/ge'
```

(assuming there's no escaped quotes inside (or outside) the quotes).

But, given the effort it would require, you might as well use a proper csv parser or do it whole with a perl-like regular expression engine.

Comment: I don't think this is the solution he should be looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely not for GNU cut, at least:

`/* The delimeter character for field mode. */
static unsigned char delim;`

*(as seen in GNU coreutils source)*