# How to rename files with sed and csv

Tags: bash, shell, sed, rename, csv

I'm new with Linux, `sed`, and `awk` but I don't mind challenging myself on new ideas.  That being said, I understand the purpose and how to use `rename` and `sed` for a common event such as adding a `$date` or removing a `_1234` from all the files.  However, I want to figure out how to rename 100's of files that have no relation to one another other than the file type.

Renaming example:

- old name alpha.ai renamed to omega.ai
- old name pie32.ai renamed to apple.ai
- old name xmas.ai renamed to santa.ai

I originally used a bash script to pull all the names to a .csv file and placed them in column A.  In column B I wrote in the new names.  Now since there is not a common event occurring how could you write `sed` or the like to do this??

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.ai
do
        mv $i $(echo $i | sed "a1,b1")

done
```

Comment: It is tricky to rename all special characters by automated scripts, you can find a link to my script in this answer: http://superuser.com/a/858671/365691

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you happen to have a file that looks like this:

```
old_name1, new_name1
old_name2, new_name2
old_name3, new_name3
```

You can do a dirty little trick:

```
sed 's/^/mv -vi "/;s/, /" "/;s/$/";/' < names.csv | bash -
```

The sed comamnds (delimited by semicolons) does this (`s` is for substitute, `/` is used as a delimiter, any other character would do, `@` is often used as well):

- `s/^/mv -vi "/` - adds `mv -vi "` at the beginning of each line (`^` is beginning of line);
- `s/, /" "/` - replaces comma followed by a space with `" "`;
- `s/$/";/` - appends double quotes to all lines (`$` means end of line)

and hence the output of `sed` will be this:

```
mv -vi "old_name1" "new_name1"
mv -vi "old_name2" "new_name2"
mv -vi "old_name3" "new_name3"
```

which will be fed to `bash` to execute. The quotes around filenames are not mandatory, they just guard any possible spaces in the filenames (however they will defintely not help against spaces followed by a comma, since that is used as delimiter). the `-v` instructs `mv` to display what it is doing (in case something goes wrong, you'll know what happened), `-i` will cause it to ask if it were to overwrite already existing file.

Comment: I get a mv: missing destination??

Comment: Awesome answer, works exactly as stated.

Answer (score 3):

There are several quoting problems in your script. It will mangle file names containing special characters: whitespace, `\[?*-`.

**Always use double quotes around variable substitutions `"$i"` and command substitutions `"$(sed …)".` Without double quotes, the value of the variable is interpreted as a list of whitespace-separated wildcard patterns, and each pattern is replaced by the list of matching file names (if there are no matches, the pattern is left alone).

Also, if a file name begins with `-`, it will be interpreted as an option by `mv` and possibly by `echo`. Pass `--` first to tell the command that there will be no more options.

```
for i in *.ai; do
  mv -- "$i" "$(printf '%s\n' "$i" | sed 's,a1,b1,')"
done
```

(This still assumes that your file names don't contain newlines.) (I also fixed the `sed` argument into what you presumably meant.)

---

If your list of file names is plain comma-separated with no quotes, you can parse it with a shell script. This assumes that there are no commas or newlines in any file name.

```
while IFS=, read -r from to junk; do
  mv -- "$from" "$to"
done <"$files_to_rename.csv"
```

If your input file is a CSV file with possible quoting, use a real CSV parser. Don't try to roll your own. See [Is there a robust command line tool for processing csv files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7425/is-there-a-robust-command-line-tool-for-processing-csv-files) For example, in Python (with the CSV on standard input):

```
import csv, os, sys
for line in csv.reader(sys.stdin):
    (source, dest) = line
    os.rename(source, dest)
```

Answer (score 2):

If your files have funny characters (`'`,`"`,`\`,`$`), you can loop over the file and read it into a bash array.

```
while IFS=, read -r -a arr; do mv "${arr[@]}"; done <files.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

When faced with this sort of problem I usually to the sed/bash trick by hand.

1. I either write an editor macro or a silly little program that reads in the csv file and writes lines of the form 'mv file1 file2'.
2. Then I run the script (or macro) and save the output to run-my-cmds.sh
3. Inspect run-my-cmds.sh visually to make sure it will to the right things
4. bash run-my-cmds.sh