# Parse csv using awk

Tags: awk, csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a robust command line tool for processing csv files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7425/is-there-a-robust-command-line-tool-for-processing-csv-files)

I am trying to parse the second line in a file (which contains commas within double quotes)

> "100 Watt A19 10,000 Hour - Clear Light
>   Bulb",American-Light-Bulb-Mfg,552,Indoor Living>Home
>   Furnishings>Lighting>Light Bulbs,"Product Code: H20821  Energy Used:
>   100 Watts  Rated Life: 10,000 Hours  Volts: 130  Base: E26 - Medium
>   Screw (standard household base)  Length: 4.45 Inches  Diameter: 2.375
>   Inches  Bulb Type:
>   A19",1.75,Yes,http://www.buylighting.com/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=H20821&click=104182,http://www.buylighting.com/v/vspfiles/photos/H20821-2T.jpg,,New,,,0.1,H20821,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,.25,Absolute,,,,,,,

```
head -2 file.csv | tail -1 | awk -F',' '{print $1}'
```

But it outputs:

```
"100 Watt A19 10
```

How can I use `awk` to get `"100 Watt A19 10,000 Hour - Clear Light Bulb"` as the value of `$1`? Also how can I use `awk` to get `"Product Code: H20821 Energy Used: 100 Watts Rated Life: 10,000 Hours Volts: 130 Base: E26 - Medium Screw (standard household base) Length: 4.45 Inches Diameter: 2.375 Inches Bulb Type: A19"` as the value of $5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not something `awk` is terribly good at, try using `perl` instead:

```
head -n 2 file.csv |
  tail -n 1 |
  perl -lne '@a = /((?:".*?"|.)*?)(?:,|$)/g; print $a[0]'
```