# What's a safe and portable way to split a string in shell programming?

Tags: shell, shell-script, split, portability

When writing a shell script, I often want to split a string. Here's a very simple example:

```
for dir in $(echo $PATH | tr : " "); do
    [[ -x "$dir"/"$1" ]] && echo $dir
done
```

This will search each directory in the $PATH for an executable with the same name as `$1`. Pretty straightforward, it runs well, but breaks if a directory in my $PATH contains a whitespace in its name.

**What's the recommended way to split a string at the occurrence of a recurrent separator?**

Ideally, the solution would be able to run on (fairly) old shells, namely ksh88.

Comment: See [How to iterate through a comma-separated list and execute a command for each entry](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/63931) (which doesn't address the [specificities of `$PATH`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/64173)).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just set `IFS` according to you needs and let the shell perform word splitting:

```
IFS=':'
for dir in $PATH; do
    [ -x "$dir"/"$1" ] && echo $dir
done
```

This works in `bash`, `dash` and `ksh`, but tested only with the latest versions.

Comment: Thanks! How can I set back `IFS` to its original default values, once the processing is done?

Comment: Nevermind, I store the default value of `IFS` in a temp variable, which allows me to restore IFS easily. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Either that, or force the shell to execute the given piece of code in a separate shell instance: `(IFS=:; for … done)`. Of course, this is useful only if you not need anything later from whatever was set inside the loop.

Comment: @rahmu: O.K., but be careful: `IFS` is often *unset* by default, which is *not* the same as being the empty string. When restoring it, you need to preserve that distinction.

Comment: @ruakh, while it is possible and allowed by POSIX, and it would make sense for a shell to have `$IFS` unset by default, it is not the case in any shell that I know. All the Bourne like shells I know have `IFS=$' \t\n'` in their initial IFS (with the exception of `zsh` which also has `\0` (since it can))

Comment: `PATH="$PWD/*:/bin:/usr/bin"; mkdir \*; cp /bin/ls \*/foo` and try your snippet with `ls`. You missed `set -f`, see [Stephane Chazelas's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/64173).

Answer (score 13):

The obvious solution would be to use the shell word splitting, but beware of a few gotchas:

```
IFS=:
set -o noglob
for dir in $PATH''; do
    dir=${dir:-.}
    [ -x "${dir%/}/$1" ] && printf "%s\n" "$dir"
done
```

You need `set -o noglob` because when a variable is left unquoted, both *word splitting* and *filename generation* (*globbing*) are performed on it and here you only want *word splitting* (for instance, in the unlikely event that `$PATH` contains `/usr/local/*bin*`, you want it do look in the `/usr/local/*bin*` folder, not in `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/sbin`..., and if `PATH` contains `/*/*/*/../../../*/*/*/*/../../../*/*/*/*`, you don't want it to bring your machine down)

An empty `$PATH` component means the current directory (`.`), not `/`. `$dir/$1` wouldn't be correct in that case. The work around is either to write `$dir${dir:+/}$1` or to change `$dir` to `.` in that case (which gives a more useful output when displayed with `printf '%s\n' "$dir"`.

`//foo` is not necessarily the same as `/foo`, so if `/` is in `$PATH`, you don't want `$dir/$1`, which would be `//$1`. Hence the `${dir%/}` to strip a trailing slash.

Then, there are a few other problems:

For `$PATH`, `":"` is a field *separator* while for `$IFS`, it is a field *terminator* (yes, I know, `S` is for ***S**eparator*, blame ksh and POSIX for standardizing the ksh behaviour).

So if `$PATH` is `/usr/bin:/bin:` (which is bad practice but still commonly found), that means `"/usr/bin"`, `"/bin"` and `""` (that is, the current directory), while the shell word splitting (all POSIX shells except `zsh`) will split that into `/usr/bin` and `/bin` only.

If `$PATH` is set but empty, that means: *"look in the current directory only"*.
While shells (including those that treat `$IFS` as a separator) will expand it to an empty list.

Appending the `''` to `$PATH` above works around both issues.

Last but not least. If `$PATH` is unset, then that has a special meaning which is: *look in the system default search list*, which unfortunately means something different depending on who (what command) you ask.

```
$ env -u PATH bash -c 'type usbipd'
usbipd is /usr/local/sbin/usbipd
$ env -u PATH ksh -c 'type usbipd'
ksh: whence: usbipd: not found
```

And basically, in your script, you'd have to guess what that default search path is in the context that matters to you.

Note that POSIX leaves the behaviour unspecified when `$PATH` is unset or empty, so won't help you there. That also means that what I said above may not apply to some past, current or future POSIX/Unix systems.

In short, parsing `$PATH` to try and find out where a command would be run from is a tricky business.

There is a standard command for that, which is `command`:

```
ls_path=$(command -v ls)
```

But what one may ask is: why do you want to know?

Now onto restoring IFS to its default value:

```
oldIFS=$IFS
IFS=:
...
IFS=$oldIFS
```

will work in practice in most cases but is not guaranteed to work by POSIX.

The reason is that if `$IFS` was previously unset which means *default splitting behaviour* (that is in POSIX shells, split on space, tab or newline), after those commands, it will end up set but empty (which means *no splitting*).

Another potential problem is if you generalise that approach and use it in a lot of different functions, then if in the `...` part above, you're calling a function that does the same thing (makes a copy of `$IFS` in `$oldIFS`), then you're going to loose the original `$oldIFS` and restore the wrong `$IFS`.

Instead  you could use subshells when possible:

```
(
  IFS=:
  ...
)
# only the subshell's IFS was affected, the parent still has its own IFS
```

My approach is to set $IFS (and turn `set -o noglob` on or off) *every time* I need word splitting (which is rare) and not bother restoring the previous  value. Of course, that doesn't work if your script calls someone else's code that doesn't follow that practice and assumes a default word splitting behaviour.

Comment: Parsing `$PATH` was the simplest short example I could come up with. Splitting a string with non-whitespace delimiters is a common problem I run into. I wanted to know how members here dealt with it in a robust and portable way.

Comment: Well, at least, you'll have learnt that if the string ends with a delimiter, you won't get an empty element, and that you need `set -f` to avoid the other side effect of leaving a variable unquoted. A lot of this applies to other variables of the same form like `$MANPATH`, `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`...

Comment: Yes, definitely. Thank you very much for the answer :)

Comment: There may be a better way, but you can distinguish between a null parameter and an unset parameter by comparing `${FOO:-x}` and `${FOO-x}`. The two are equivalent for an unset parameter, but not a null parameter.

Comment: @chepner, a common trick to save and restore IFS, is to write it `oIFS=$IFS; ${IFS+:} unset oIFS` and then same to restore: `IFS=$oIFS; ${oIFS+:} unset IFS`, but there's still an issue if there are nested functions using that trick.

Comment: Clever; it took me a moment to parse that.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to read a fixed number of fields into variables, you can use this method:

```bsh
input="age:30"

IFS=':' read -r first_field second_field <<< "$input"

echo "$first_field"
echo "$second_field"
```

I found it on [Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

The `-r` tells `read` that is should not treat backslashes as special.