# sort CSV by number of column in rows?

Tags: text-processing, awk, columns

I have multiple CSV files with many records. The total number of rows should be 134. I have many files, and each rows has its own number of columns (from 15 to 200). I need to sort them according to their number of columns.

I was able to count a file's columns using:

```
$ awk -F"," '{print NF}' file # 1.csv
```

... which gives something like:

```
134
134
134
5
25
133
...
```

Now, I would like to add these numbers to each row, so that I can later sort my rows according to it. How can I add this information at the beginning of each, and sort?

I'd also like to split the files with value=134 into 1 file other by their respective count.

small INPUT file example (this is 3 rows):

```
2,"A.B.C.D",50,"SDf3oa701-ab73-a0pcs90","7012218969217-1413752517-32448","SDf3oa701-ab73-a0pcs90","SIP",,"<99999@sipgw5003.com>;tag=70122","<8888888@X.Y.Z.W>",17,0,"00:01:57.827 GMT Oct 20 2014","00:00:00.000 UTC Jan 01 1970","00:01:57.870 GMT Oct 20 2014",3,"sp3",1904,"sp3",1904,"realm_IN","realmTERM_OUT",,,,"::",0,"::",0,,"::",0,"::",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,"::",0,"::",0,,"::",0,"::",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,"::",0,"::",0,,"::",0,"::",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,"::",0,"::",0,,"::",0,"::",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,"Sw-buildabcd","GMT-03:00",0,"8888888@X.Y.Z.W",,,,,,"X.Y.Z.W:50","A.S.D.F:50","A.S.D.F:50","A.S.D.F:50",,1,2,1,404,"8888888@A.S.D.F",,,4493101
2,"A.B.C.D",50,,,,4493105
2,"A.B.C.D",50,,"88888@B.D.S.E",,,4493106
```

Comment: Wow, I spent more time than I thought fixing this question... Next time, please make sure you read our [How to ask](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting a question. By the way, I was unable to *clarify" your last sentence.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us an example of your input file and the output you would like from that example. The solutions will depend on the format of your input files. Most importantly what you have to delimit fields. Are columns separated by spaces? Tabs? Commas?

Comment: Thanks. So, should row2 be considered to have 4 fields or 7? Can you have commas within a field? What is the output you would like to have from that input?

Comment: @terdon row2 & row3 should have 134 fields , same as row1
i dont want to add 0 values at this stage, rather i want to sort them by number of fields

Comment: @HusseinKray So in your example they all have the same number of fields and won't need sorting ?

Comment: @jidder  no , i have many rows with vairalble length, this why  i will seprate them to multiple files later on .. ( the correct nb of fields is 134)

Comment: They should have 134 fields? One hundred and thirty four? Why? Please show us a workable example. In order to help you, we need to see both input and desired output. If you need 134 fields, show us a file with 134 fields. Otherwise, show us a dummy file with 5 fields and explain what output you want to see from it.

Comment: @terdon both answers below helps alot to fix the files i have, the files i have are CDR ( call detail records) ,  it is complicated to give a golden rule since amny rows have different forms, . i marked the Q as answered, if i need more help i will make sure to post a new Q with proper input\output\question 
**thanks alot**

Comment: by the way INPUT-ROW#1 is a required format for each row , and each row should have 134 field ( this is the CDR format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think this is what you want
Add `-F,` for comma separated.
E.g `awk -F, '$(NF+1)=NF' file`

#### Add Number to end of rows

```
 awk '$(NF+1)=NF' file
```

*Input*

```
1
1 2 3
1 2
1 2 3 4 5 6
a b
```

*Output*

```
1 1
1 2 3 3
1 2 2
1 2 3 4 5 6 6
a b 2
```

#### Sort Rows

```
 awk '{a[NF]=a[NF]?a[NF]"\n"$0:$0;x=x<NF?NF:x}END{for(i=1;i<=x;i++)if(i in a)print a[i]}'
```

*Input*

```
1
1 2 3
1 2
1 2 3 4 5 6
a b
```

*Output*

```
1
1 2
a b
1 2 3
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

#### Print to different files

Using field length of 4 for example, change to 134 or whatever you want for yours

```
 awk '{print > (NF>=4?"LargeFile.txt":"SmallFile.txt")}' file
```

*Input*

```
1
1 2 3
1 2
1 2 3 4 5 6
a b
```

*Output*

`LargeFile.txt`

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

`SmallFile.txt`

```
1
1 2 3
1 2
a b
```

Comment: that would work , but i have a comma separated values (CSV files)

Comment: @HusseinKray that's why _you need to show your input_. Also, do you want the lines from all CSVs do be mixed? Separate? Sorted? You need to show us an example of both your input and your desired output.

Comment: @HusseinKray Add `-F,` after awk

Comment: @Jidder `awk` isn't a native CSV parser : there may be commas in quoted fields. The OP may need a [more robust command line tool for processing CSV files](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7425/is-there-a-robust-command-line-tool-for-processing-csv-files).

Comment: @JohnWHSmith OP seems happy with the output for fields in his post, but yes if it has embedded commas then depending on which version of awk they are using all of this may be useless.

Comment: @jidder no comma in quoted fields so this wont be an issue

Comment: @HusseinKray Okay well is that what you wanted ?

Comment: @Jidder, that is exactly what i want  , appreciate if you can tell me how to handle these input as CSV , not space-seperated  (thanks a lot )

Comment: @HusseinKray Add `-F,` after awk for comma separated

Comment: @slm I'd appreciate it if you didn't edit my code purely for your personal preference of formatting. Also `For e.g` doesn't even make sense

Comment: @Jidder - I edited more than that. You had formatting, typos. and punctuation issues. It's not my personal preference, I'm making your answer easier to read too. Your first paragraph is oddly formatted too. For e.g. means For example. If you disagree roll it back as you've done. But I've done enough editing to know what works/looks better than what you had originally posted. The posts here are read on a variety of devices, not just desktop browsers, so keep that in mind as well when   posting.

Comment: @slm I had no typos? Also e.g means exempli gratia(literally for example). For e.g is like saying 'for for example' so maybe do some research before incorrectly editing answers. As for it 'looking better' with your formatting that is completely your opinion/preference. Also doing a lot of editing doesn't necessarily mean your are good at it

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @terdon's answer, but with `sed`:

```
{ seq -s, 10; seq -s, 5; seq -s, 15; } | 
tee - -
```

That's my infile - it looks like:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15
```

I can then do:

```
sed 'h;s/[^,]*//g;G;s/\n/ /' | sort -t\  -nk1,1
```

...which gets...

```
,,,, 1,2,3,4,5
,,,, 1,2,3,4,5
,,,, 1,2,3,4,5
,,,,,,,,, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
,,,,,,,,, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
,,,,,,,,, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15
,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15
,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15
```

The numbers are not there, but the count is sure enough, I guess. To remove the leading commas I can just do:

```
PIPELINE | sed 's/,* //'
```

...which gets...

```
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15
```

Perhaps not the most auspicious answer thus far, but the primary reason I decided to write this was that you mention you want to write lines with 134 comma-separated entries to another file. This, as it happens, is a simple matter with `sed`. For example - lets say I wanted to write the lines with 10 fields from the above sequence to a `file2`:

```
PIPELINE | sed '/^\([^,]*,[^,]*\)\{9\}$/w file2'
cat file2
```

#### OUTPUT

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

I use `\{9\}` above because it specifies 9 instances of the pattern - which makes 9 delimiters to 10 delimited fields. Ranges are simply handled as well:

```
PIPELINE | sed '/^\([^,]*,[^,]*\)\{4,9\}$/w file2'
cat file2
```

#### OUTPUT

```
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

Answer (score 1):

This will add the number of (comma separated) fields to the beginning of each line, print the line and then sort everything:

```
awk -F"," '{print NF,$0}' *csv | sort -nk1,1
```

The `-n` is numerical sort and the `-k1,1` ensures that it is only sorted on the first field. To remove the number of fields after sorting, use:

```
awk -F"," 'print NF,$0' *csv | sort -nk1,1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2-
```

**NOTE**: This will break very easily depending on your actual data. Can you have commas within fields? Can you have fields spanning multiple lines? This is a very naive approach and can't deal with any of that.