# Pivot file values

Tags: linux

I have a file where the first column is the key.  The rows can have up to 2800 delimiters.  I need to pivot the data from rows to columns.  Below is the sample input and required output.

### Source File

```
123,A,B,,,,AC,DF,,,,,,,,,,,,n 
567,A,B,,C,D,,,,,,,,, 7
89,C,B
```

### Output

```
123,A
123,B
123,
123,
.
.
123,AC
123,DF
567,A
567,B
567,C
567,D
567,7
89,C
89,B
```

Please advise.

Comment: I am not really sure why we have a CSV tag.  IMO the easiest tool to jump to for standard CSV would be `python`, but this site is not really supposed to be for programming questions except for "shell scripting".  Maybe a bit of a grey area.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7425/is-there-a-robust-command-line-tool-for-processing-csv-files

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat file
123,A,B,,,,AC,DF,,,,,,,,,,,,n
567,A,B,,C,D,,,,,,,,, 7
89,C,B
```

```
$ awk -F, 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } { for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) if ($i != "") print $1, $i }' file
123,A
123,B
123,AC
123,DF
123,n
567,A
567,B
567,C
567,D
567, 7
89,C
89,B
```

This assumes that the data is in a *simple* CSV format that does not require any quotes (no embedded commas or newlines in any field).  The `awk` code simply iterates over the comma-delimited fields of each line, from field 2 onwards, and prints them along with the first field on new lines.  Empty fields are ignored.  If you don't want to ignore empty fields (it's unclear in the question), remove the `if ($i != "")` bit in the code.

Answer (score 2):

Using Miller (http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/) with

```
mlr --nidx --fs "," reshape -r '[^1]' -o item,value \
then filter -S -x '$value==""' \
then cut -f 1,value input.txt
```

you have

```
123,A
123,B
123,AC
123,DF
123,n
567,A
567,B
567,C
567,D
567, 7
89,C
89,B
```

If you want also null value is

```
mlr --nidx --fs "," reshape -r '[^1]' -o item,value \
then cut -f 1,value input.txt
```

And you will have

```
123,A
123,B
123,
123,
123,
123,AC
123,DF
123,
123,
123,
123,
123,
123,
123,
123,
123,
123,
123,n
567,A
567,B
567,
567,C
567,D
567,
567,
567,
567,
567,
567,
567,
567, 7
89,C
89,B
```