# AWK Command - Edit Blank "Cell" in CSV to Text Value

Tags: linux, awk, command-line

I am sorry if my question is more a typographical error, but I have been trying to sort this out for a while now and sadly, I cannot get this to work. Perhaps I should use the sed command, but I haven't figured out how to specify a column in sed and despite being a beginner, I have a bit more experience with the awk command.

So here is the goal; I have a CSV file, file1, that has a column (14) where some of the rows have null (blank) values, while other rows have values.  I still want all the other columns in the output, but just to change the blank (empty [null]) columns in column 14 to have a new value of **NA**.

### Example:

**Column14**
Value1
Value2

Value3

I am trying to use the awk command to locate any blank row in column 14 and if found enter a new text value of NA to the cell.

Here is the command I was trying, but my new file still has blank cells in column 14.  I would appreciate any help.  Thank you.

### **Command:**

```
awk -F"," 'BEGIN {OFS=","} $14 == "" { $14 = "NA" }  {print}' file1 > file2
```

### **GOAL:**

### Example:

**Column14**
Value1
Value2
NA
Value3

Thank you all for taking the time to read and assist.

### **UPDATE**

As requested, here is some sample data.

```
"employee_number","employee_login","is_active","send_pkg_email","send_na_email","last_name","first_name","department","title","phone_number","employee_type","email","charge_code","area_code","mailstop","roomid"
"103293","jsmith@company.com","Y","","","Smith","Jessica","","","+1 (650) 3530975","Employee","jsmith@company.com","","LOC0028.03","","03.C.01H"
"103295","fredl@company.com","Y","","","Long","Fred","","","+1 (415) 9449428","Employee","fredl@company.com","","LOC0025.01","","01.D.04B"
"103297","lcheng@company.com","Y","","","Cheng","Laura","","","+1 (650) 8623342","Contingent","lcheng@company.com","","","",""
"103307","cfb@company.com","Y","","","Brown","Chris","","","+1 (512) 9644927","Employee","cfb@company.com","","ATX0607.16","","16.B.10D"
"103310","stanwang@company.com","Y","","","Williams","Stan","","","+1 (650) 8048591","Employee","stanwang@company.com","","LOC0061.03","","03.D.01B"
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show some sample data that actually has (at least) 14 columns with both empty and non-empty values and that reproduces your problem. Check if your input file has rows that contain whitespace only in column 14.

Comment: Your awk script works for me.

Comment: @Bodo I added the sample data you requested.  When I run my command my output file still shows the blank cells as blank "".

Comment: Unlike a lot of "CSV" questions here, your input file is properly formatted CSV so you should probably use a real CSV parser to work with it (just splitting fields on commas isn't good enough).   See [Is there a robust command line tool for processing csv files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7425/is-there-a-robust-command-line-tool-for-processing-csv-files) - personally, i'd use either `csvkit` or perl's `Text::CSV` module.   [miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) is pretty good too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ perl -MText::CSV=csv -e '
  $csv = Text::CSV->new();
  while(my $row = $csv->getline(ARGV)) {
    $row->[13] = "NA" if ($row->[13] eq "");
    $csv->say(STDOUT, $row);
  };' input.csv
```

Note that perl arrays begin from 0, not 1 - so the 14th field is element 13 of the `$row` arrrayref.

```
employee_number,employee_login,is_active,send_pkg_email,send_na_email,last_name,first_name,department,title,phone_number,employee_type,email,charge_code,area_code,mailstop,roomid
103293,jsmith@company.com,Y,,,Smith,Jessica,,,"+1 (650) 3530975",Employee,jsmith@company.com,,LOC0028.03,,03.C.01H
103295,fredl@company.com,Y,,,Long,Fred,,,"+1 (415) 9449428",Employee,fredl@company.com,,LOC0025.01,,01.D.04B
103297,lcheng@company.com,Y,,,Cheng,Laura,,,"+1 (650) 8623342",Contingent,lcheng@company.com,,NA,,
103307,cfb@company.com,Y,,,Brown,Chris,,,"+1 (512) 9644927",Employee,cfb@company.com,,ATX0607.16,,16.B.10D
103310,stanwang@company.com,Y,,,Williams,Stan,,,"+1 (650) 8048591",Employee,stanwang@company.com,,LOC0061.03,,03.D.01B
```

The line with employee_number `103297` now has **NA** in the 14th field.

BTW, the output fields here are double-quoted only when necessary (e.g. when they contain a space. or if any of them contained a comma, they'd be quoted too).  If you prefer all fields in the output to be quoted as in your input file, change the `$csv = Text::CSV->new();` line to:

```
$csv = Text::CSV->new({always_quote => 1});
```

[Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/release/Text-CSV) has numerous other options.  e.g. if you use `$csv = Text::CSV->new({always_quote => 1, strict => 1});` it will also trigger an error if any of the input rows have a different number of fields.  See `man Text::CSV` for details.

---

Alternatively, there's a simple fix to your awk script:

```
awk -F"," 'BEGIN {OFS=","}; $14 == "\"\"" { $14 = "\"NA\"" };1' input.csv
```

This highlights a problem with just comma-splitting CSV files.  It's impossible to distinguish between `"` characters as wrappers around field data and `"` characters being part of the field data...because there is no such distinction with this simple split method.

Field 14 **isn't** empty when you're just splitting the input line by commas.  It contains two quote characters (`""`).

This awk one-liner will also break if any of the fields contain a comma character.  That's another reason why it's better to use a CSV parser.

See [Is there a robust command line tool for processing csv files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7425/is-there-a-robust-command-line-tool-for-processing-csv-files).

There's also a good awk csv parser at https://github.com/geoffroy-aubry/awk-csv-parser

Comment: Because my reputation is under 15, I cannot up-vote this, but this worked for me.  I see your points around using a proper CSV parser and I will look into this as well.  I can confirm the AWK works for me and I see my mistake in that I needed with the "" characters.  Thank you very much for your assistance with this.

Comment: @jesse i made a minor fix to the script. the previous version would modify field 14 if it was empty *or if it contained `0`*.  now it only modifies it if it is empty.

Comment: Okay wonderful.  Thank you for revisiting and making the adjustment @cas.

Answer (score 1):

Column 14 does not contain an empty string, but `""`, so you need to check for two quotes (which have to be escaped):

```
awk -F"," 'BEGIN {OFS=","} $14 == "\"\"" { $14 = "NA" } {print}' file1 > file2
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing.  Between yours and the comments from @cas, I was able to get this working.  Very much appreciated.